# How do I create a search which looks for matching data in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a search box which checks the input and sees if it matches a name of a town.

My data is organised like so (fictitious data btw):

```
var markers = {
    towns: {
        "London": {lat: -83.68088192646843, lng: -125.270751953125},
        "Paris": {lat: -58.1548020417031, lng: -21.318115234375},
    }
}
```

So to clarify:

- Take the textbox input, `var query`
- Search through the towns, `var results`
- `if (query === results)` do something e.g. make an alert

Thanks.

Edit:

I have been able to make a test as follows:

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    var query = $("#search").val();
    var results = "hi";
    if (query === results) {
        alert("booyah");
    }   
})
```

This works, however as you can see I don't know how to store the towns in `var results`.

Edit #2: Would this work?

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    var query = $("#search").val();
    for (var town in markers.towns) {
        if (query !== markers.towns[town]) {
            alert("booyah");
        }           
    }
})
```

Comment: That is a pretty specific clarification (i.e. answer material). Are you sure you can't work this one out yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax to loop through my array and then check against the answers. Also, whenever I've tried to do to store the query it doesn't work. I've made tests such as `var query = $("#search").val()` and then tried to `alert(query)`. Other methods I've tried involve `search.value` but nothing works.

Comment: @musefan see the edit I have made to original question.

Comment: For Edit 2: Try `if (markers.towns[query])`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your object is not an array.
this case could be quite simple:

```
var coordinates = (function () {
    var markers = {
        towns: {
            "London": {lat: -83.68088192646843, lng: -125.270751953125},
            "Paris": {lat: -58.1548020417031, lng: -21.318115234375},
        }
    };
    return {
        find = function (city) {
             markers.towns[city] || null;
        }
    };
})();
```

the find method will return your value object or null.

Comment: Is there anyway to use my current object structure and can you explain the find function to me? I'm new to objects and json etc.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following, using a hard-coded query variable, it works fine:

```
var markers = {
    towns: {
        "London": {lat: -83.68088192646843, lng: -125.270751953125},
        "Paris": {lat: -58.1548020417031, lng: -21.318115234375}
    }
}

var query = "london";   // Test with different capitalization.
for (var town in markers.towns) {
    // If the current town name matches the input field (case insensitive)
    if (town.toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase()) {
        alert("booyah");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. The query part is fine, but it's either the loop or comparison that doesn't.

Comment: I have tested this in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/sYCfx/) and it does in fact work. Though when I use it, the map no longer loads. I can't think why though.

Comment: I have figured it out, I needed to put the search inside the same function as the markers object. Thanks!